# Access logged in user via Ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have read a lot about this but I can't seem to solve it, so I am just going around in circles. I am trying to access a logged user via an API route I have setup using;

```
$user = Auth:user();
```

The problem is; $user is always null when I make an ajax request but the user is not null when I access the API route in the browser. For example entering; api.example.com/v1/myaccount

I have solved many problems along the way such as turning on sessions for all subdomains and adding the following to the api route middleware.

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
];
```

Previously the url was returning a 404 error via Ajax but worked fine in the browser. Now the $user variable is just empty as if no user is logged. But I have logged normally.

I am using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Where are you Ajax routes pointing to? I do this a lot and never have issues so ill share the way i do it.

My Ajax requests look something like this:

(Note: ajaxSetup is mandatory)

```
$.ajaxSetup( {
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $( 'meta[name=_token]' ).attr( 'content' )
    }
  } );

  $('#ID').change(function(){

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/super/cool/route',
        data: { stuff : stuff},
        success: function(data) {


        }
      })
    }
  });
```

And the route will point to a controller.

I think the problem for you is that you are not including the "Auth" in the top of the file. On each controller you see:

```
use Auth;
```

Check and make sure that is where the ajax routes are pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is **No!** You can't do that.

I think you have confuse between `Ajax` with POST request from `HTML Form`.
Because `Ajax` call has different sessions.